# How to pass generic ArrayList<usertype> in simple ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, spinner, getview

I am creating a simple Adapter without any customization. i just want the items displayed in the spinner is from the gettersetter class. i override a getview method of adapter but it gave me addresses of pointers instead of items. Here is my code for better understanding.

```
UserType users = new ArrayList<>();
    users = db.getUsers(groupid);
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(),android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,users){
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            textView.setText(users.get(position).getUsername());
            return view;
        }
    };
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

with this method the number of items displayed in spinner is correct but items names are not displayed.

Comment: your question not describe the problem. explain more. As far as I get you want to fire some event on activity two on click of activity one RIGHT?

Comment: use `LocalBrodcast` from First activity

Comment: Can u explain what LocalBrodcast.

Comment: @NishantSambyal I have added answer for broadcast receiver

Comment: thank u.. Let me apply that code

Answer (score 0):

`BroadcastReceiver` For **Class2**

```
private BroadcastReceiver updateProfileBroadcast = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Fire your event
    }
};
```

Register **Broadcast** in `onResume()`

```
registerReceiver(updateProfileBroadcast, new IntentFilter("KEY"));
```

Now fire **Broadcast** on **MainActivity**

```
    Intent intent = new Intent("KEY");
    getActivity().sendBroadcast(intent);
```